# How to store data structures when certain operations need to be performed in faster than O(n) time?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, time-complexity, storage

(I'm a newcomer to databases, so apologies if this is a strange question. Feel free to disagree with my point of view if you think I'm not thinking clearly.)

Some data structures have support for operations that can be completed in better than `O(n)` time, where `n` is the number of items currently stored in the structure. For example, [heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) allow for `O(log n)` insertion and deletion of items. I don't understand the correct way to store such data structures inside a database.

> **Question.** In regards to databases in general, and in regards to Django 2.2.7 and Postgres 12.0 specifically, what is the correct way to store data structures when faster than `O(n)` operations are required?

The remainder of this question is elaboration and discussion.

Suppose, for example, that our database consists of two tables, one called `Person` and one called `Task`. Each `Task` has an associated `Person` field called `assignee` representing the person to whom the task was assigned, and an associated `int` field called `priority` representing the urgency of the task.

Now any given person in the real world might we might want to query the database for the highest priority `Task` that they've been assigned. The simplest way to service such a request is just to go through each row of `Task`, one at a time. Unfortunately, assuming that each `Person` has at least one task, this quickly becomes inefficient as the number of rows in `Person` grows.

To improve the time-complexity of the query, we might add another column to the `Person` table with type `list(Task)` called `tasks`. The idea is that this field will maintain a list of all tasks that this person has been assigned. This change causes the database to use a little more space, but greatly improves performance when someone asks for the highest-priority task with which they're assigned. (I'm not an expert, but I think this process of adding redundant information to improve performance is called 'denormalization' - can someone who knows their stuff comment and just confirm that I'm using this term correctly?)

Anyway, even with the aforementioned denormalization in place, there's still an issue. Namely, what happens if someone has a huge number of tasks associated to them? In this case, even if the `Person` table includes a `tasks` field, the amount of time it takes the database to service the request could be very high.

In my computer science degree, we were taught to solve these kinds of problems by choosing appropriate data structures. In this case, we would probably change the type of the `tasks` field, so that instead of pointing to an object of type `list(Task)` it instead points to an object of type `heap(Task)`.

However the correct way to do this is very non-obvious to me. If the heap is stored as an array of items on the hard drive, and if every operation with the heap requires us to load the entire array into memory, perform the operation, and then store it again, well now we're back to `O(n)` time complexity just to perform one insertion or pop operation, which usually take `O(log n)` time.

So my question is really how to avoid this.

Comment: Yes, that would be called [database denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization).

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand the correct way to store such data structures inside a database.

You don't store *data structures* inside a database, you store *data* inside a database using the specific data structures offered by the database.

You mentioned PostgreSQL. That is a specific product, broadly compatible with the SQL database standard, using data structures compatible with the [relational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) of data. It defines the data structures it uses, and the time-complexity of using them. In your specific example, relational databases offer a data structure to solve your problem, called an [index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index).

> In my computer science degree, we were taught to solve these kinds of problems by choosing appropriate data structures.

Right. Having chosen the appropriate data structure, you then use a data storage product that implements it to store your *data*. A [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) is not a thing that can be stored.

Note that relational databases are just one way of storing and representing data. They have proven to be very useful, and offer a variety of data structures (most notably, the table and the index). But there are other data structures that cannot be implemented well by a relational database. In which case you use a different product. [Redis](https://redis.io/), for example, bills itself as a [*data-structures server*](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro), and offers a specific set of data structures and access patterns that are quite different from a relational database. [Graph databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) would be another example.

Comment: I've just taken a little look at Redis, and it seems this wouldn't be an appropriate database framework in cases where the database ends up too large to fit in main memory. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

The big-O notation may be misleading. For example, an index lookup is O(log n), but the base of the logarithm is so high that even the biggest possible tables don't have to read more than perhaps 6 index blocks.

It is similar with locating free space in a table. Even a large table has a free space map that is so small that locating a block with free space will be fast.

I think your concerns fall into the area of premature optimization.

Comment: Though I agree with the general idea that big O-notation can be misleading (indeed I'm usually the one to point this out), I don't really understand your comment. How can you label a solution as premature optimization when you don't know the intended goals of the software?

Comment: Indeed, take a look at the actual question: "In regards to databases in general, and in regards to Django 2.2.7 and Postgres 12.0 specifically, what is the correct way to store data structures when faster than O(n) operations are required?" This couldn't possibly be premature optimization, because faster than O(n) operations are required *by hypothesis.*

Comment: My answer talks about inserting and deleting individual rows in a table. Sorry, I thought that was what you wanted. These operations don't get significantly slower when the table is large.

Comment: Fair enough! <filler characters here>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually implement all your own data structures, what are you doing using PostgreSQL in the first place?  You use sophisticated software because it has already done those things for you.

```
create index on task (assignee, priority);

select * from task where assignee=314159 order by priority desc limit 1;
```

Unless you have tried this simple solution and it did not work, then there is nothing here which needs bespoke optimizations.